# Explanation of this code (where do i put the values?) Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As String
Dim finalValue As String

Dim cell As Excel.Range

For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
    finalValue = finalValue + CStr(cell.Value)
Next cell

ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
End Function
```

As an example, you could call it like this:

```
Sub MyMacro()
MsgBox ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange([A1:C3])
End Sub
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I found the solution (above) to my question, but i don't know where to put the values of my cells in.

i have to add horizontal cell's texts in to one cell.

for example, a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4 c1 c2 c3 c4
i need to add them in the order, each with single letter, into one single cell

Comment: Set the formula of the cell to =ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(A1:C3)  ?

Comment: how do you set the formula of the cell?

Comment: i typed that into the cell and it says NAME?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Union.  So, in a cell, something like:

```
=ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange((A1:A4,B1:B4,C1:C4))
                                 ^                 ^
```

Note the ranges are inside an inner set of parentheses, so they can get interpreted as a single argument by the function.

In your macro, you could use something like:

```
MsgBox ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(Range("a1:a4, b1:b4, c1:c4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Function ConcatRange(ParamArray m()) As String
 Dim p As Integer, x As Integer, v
 Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer, s As String
 Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
 p = UBound(m)
 s = ""
 For x = 0 To p
  nr = m(x).Rows.Count
  nc = m(x).Columns.Count
  v = m(x)
  For r = 1 To nr
   For c = 1 To nc
    s = s & v(r, c)
   Next
  Next
 Next
ConcatRange = s
End Function
```

In VBA call it like this:

```
s = ConcatRange(Range("A1:A4"), Range("B1:B4"),Range("C1:C4") )
```

and in Excel

```
=ConcatRange(A1:A4;B1:B4;C1:C4)
```

Comment: what you mean in excel? do i have to right the last code?

Comment: i typed the code, last one in the cell and it says NAME?

Comment: In order to be used in Excel you must write the code in a Module. In VBA (menu - insert - module) and then write the code there.